# Refreshing VM with limited Disk SPace

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, vhdx

I have a Hyper-V machine that crashed. I am trying to refresh it but the disk is too small when I load the disk.ISO in. I tried to expand it but I still get the screen. Is there a way to add the added disk space to the so that it sees the extra disk space and can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to resize the filesystem to let the added space be usable.

Try booting with a [Parted live cd](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and resize you filesystem, then retry the refresh process.